# How to embed app deeplink in sendgrid email template?

Tags: android, html, ios, sendgrid-api-v3

I want to send app deeplink in email with the following thymeleaf html template through sendgrid api.

```
<a th:href="@{myapp://open.myapp.com/v1/check-token}" universal="true">Click here</a>
```

But after receiving the email there is no `href` anchor. Later i found that only standard web format(url starting with `http` and `https`) are tracked by sendgrid.

[image]

So how do i send app link as a proper url in the email through sendgrid? My expectation is like bellow image

[image]